# Caching BFS traversal in an undirected and unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, c++11, graph, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I have an undirected and unweighted graph with about a million nodes - visualized in a matrix format.

Representation of a sample graph:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The red cells are blocked.

My problem is to find the shortest distance  between any two cells. The source and destination cells will be given one by one, and I need to return the shortest paths for all given cell pairs.
The traversal is manhattan only (up,down,left,right -no diagonal).No path can go through the blocked cells.

I looked at the following:

- the Floyd-warshall algorithm: but it takes too much memory.
- Dijkstra's algorithm for all nodes, but it is too slow.
- A* could work, but would still be slow  - if the shortest path needs to be found for all pairs.

Is there any other approach for it?

Since it's just a uniform matrix, I would think that there might be some pattern I am unaware of.

Can a BFS traversal be cached somehow, so that a search can resume at an already visited node rather than starting from scratch again?

Comment: What exactly do you mean be "too slow"?  What performance would be acceptable for you?  My c++17 implementation of Dijkstra finds the path from one node to every other for a graph of 145,000 vertices and 2,200,000 edges in 40 seconds.  Details:  https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Costs

Comment: from one src to other node- it takes 40s - which is all right - since its only for one node. I have to process all the nodes as src which would mean N * 40s which is impractical .

Comment: less than 15-20 mins  since i am competing with commercial tools;
parallelization would definitely help but my intention is more towards doing a pre-processing once and then querying should be faster

Answer (score 2):

If your graph is a 1000x1000 grid, then let every cell (x,y) be a "border cell" if x%100 = 0 or y%100 = 0.

This divides your graph into 100 regions separated by borders.

If you need to find a shortest path between points in the same region, then you can just use BFS within the region, and you will search at most 10K nodes.

When you need to find a path between different regions, then it will always consist of a path to a border node, maybe a path between border nodes, and then a path from a border node to the target.

You can accelerate the search by using Floyd-Warshall to precompute the shortest path distance between every pair of border cells.  There are only about 20000 of those, so this will require storing about 200 million lengths.

Your BFS search will then be limited to edges within the source region, F-W paths between the source and target regions, and edges within the target region.

This will provide a speed-up of 20-50x for worst-case searches.

Comment: This seems an intriguing approach.  It will need to be adapted to account for the red, blocked cells.  Instead of fixed 100 by 100 regions, the regions could be created on the fly so that no region contains a blocked cell.

Comment: You can just assume that the shortest path length to/from any blocked cell is infinite.

Comment: The paths cannot through the blocked cell obviously. Edited the question with these informations. Any other information you might need ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your vertices are located on an orthogonal grid, a "Manhattan" path between two cells can be calculated instantly. e.g from 1,3 to 5,4 can go 1,3; 1,4; 2,4; 3,4; 4,4; 5,4.

Since no path can go through a blocked vertex: Check as you go along and change the dimension being altered if you hit a red, blocked cell.

Your performance requirement suggests you need about 1 millisecond per path calculation ( for a million paths in in 20 minutes ).  That might just be possible if you can use Manhattan paths, otherwise no.

Here is some code to calculate the Manhattan path

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>
path(int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy)
{
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ret;
ret.push_back(std::make_pair(sx, sy));
int deltax = dx - sx;
int deltay = dy - sy;
if (deltax)
{
    int inc = 1;
    if (deltax < 0)
        inc = -1;
    int x = sx;
    do
    {
        x += inc;
        ret.push_back(std::make_pair(x, sy));
    } while (x != dx);
}
if (deltay)
{
    int inc = 1;
    if (deltay < 0)
        inc = -1;
    int y = sy;
    do
    {
        y += inc;
        ret.push_back(std::make_pair(dx, y));
    } while (y != dy);
}
return ret;
```

}

Complete application at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so76134936

Test run:

```
C:\Users\James\code\so76134936\bin>starter
Input source location (x  y ) and destination location, e.g:
 1 3 6 7
10 3 6 7
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        9.9e-06 9.9e-06 path calculation
10 3
9 3
8 3
7 3
6 3
6 4
6 5
6 6
6 7
```

test run for long path:

```
Input source location (x  y ) and destination location, e.g:
 1 3 6 7
 10 3 600 800
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls       Mean (secs) Total       Scope
       1    7.25e-05    7.25e-05    path calculation
10 3
11 3
12 3
13 3
14 3
15 3
16 3
17 3
18 3
19 3
20 3
21 3
22 3
23 3
24 3
25 3
26 3
27 3
    ...
600 791
600 792
600 793
600 794
600 795
600 796
600 797
600 798
600 799
600 800
```

Note: if blocks were accounted for, performance would be slower.

Conclusion: Your performance requirement ( 1 millisecond per path ) is achievable.

I have checked in code that checks for a blocked path.  It simply tries going around the other way and gives up if that is also blocked.  You will need something more sophisticated, but this code should give you a good place to start.  ( If you would like me to proceed further, get in touch through the github repo and we can discuss details )

Comment: changed the picture.. orthagonal grid was a powerpoint artefact. Yes.. the traversal is manhattan. 
Your instant calculation assumption is valid -if the blockages were not present - but blockages are quite frequent

Comment: takes 3 mins for around 3.5k pairs... will need to check for all pairs,c++11 with -0Fast optimization

Comment: That suggests you are taking 50 ms per path - something is wrong with your implementation.

Comment: 50ms for bfs and then reverse DFS for getting the path - i would not think its unreasonable.

Comment: Do not use bfs or dfs - they will take far too long for your performance requirement.  I thought I explained that in my answer!  Have you read it?  Is something I wrote unclear?

Comment: I had a look at the repo. error is thrown if there is a blockage but in reality path might exist. I will confirm once i implement that in couple of days. Thx for the link though. If it works  with blockages it will be very cool.

Comment: As I explained ". It simply tries going around the other way and gives up if that is also blocked. "  Please re-read the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I ultimately built my own solution based on this article. A* +  JPS where interpolation is similar to your code. https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js